# Представление ленты событий в БД

Tags: база-данных, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день

Подскажите, как лучше (правильнее) реализовать следующее. Только изучаю `Ruby(ROR)`, поэтому знаний не достаточно, буду благодарен за любые советы и прямые указания.

Система, сохраняющая изменения дополнительных полей. Изменения могут быть у пользователя либо у `item` пользователя. Как только система видит изменение дополнительного поля, которого нету в самой таблице (к примеру,  баланс для пользователя), она создает запись в таблице `events`. Самая свежая запись в таблицы `events` с учетом названия поля (`action`) и принадлежности к `object_id` (`item` пользователя либо пользователь) - это текущее значение выбранного поля.

Предполагаю делать следующим образом:

Есть три модели: Пользователи(`User`), Элементы(`Item`), События(`Event`)

Таблица events имеет следующие поля:

- `id`;
- `object_id id` элемента у которого изменилось поле;
- `user_id`;
- `action` название поля (к примеру, `changed_balance` или `changed_thumb`);
- `data` значение поля.

В качестве object_id может выступить user_id или item_id.

Пользователи и Элементы связаны

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Пользователи и События связаны

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    serialize :data
end
```

Я совсем не уверен в правильности такой структуры. Поэтому прошу совета более опытных людей.

Comment: Посмотри на papertrail и его собратьев. Твои events всё усложняют, нужны ли они на самом деле?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так сделал:

Есть модель Model, у которого поле field, за коим мы, собственно, следим и изменения сохраняем. 
Тогда:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :save_event

  private
  def save_event
   if self.field_changed?
      Event.create(
         object_id: self.id,
         action: :field
         value: self.field
      )
   end
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

field_changed? Это волшебный метод, создаваемый рельсами. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html